# Get array from variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to get an array from a variable. If it's not already an array I want to return a new array with the variable as the only entry.Example:

```
toArray('test'); // => ["test"]
toArray(['test']); // => ["test"]
```

My actual working code is:

```
var toArray;

toArray = function(o) {
  if (Array.isArray(o)) {
    return o.slice();
  } else {
    return [o];
  }
};
```

I'd like to know if there is a nicer way for that (native or with underscore.js for example).

In ruby, you can do:

```
Array('test') # => ["test"]
Array(['test']) # => ["test"]
```

Comment: Your example uses an string, not an object. Your question says "if it's not already [an array]" but returns a new array regardless. What do you really want?

Comment: It could be whatever that it's not an array: object, string, integer, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `.concat()`.

```
[].concat("test");   // ["test"]
[].concat(["test"]); // ["test"]
```

---

Arrays will be flattened into the new Array. Anything else will simply be added.

Answer (score 1):

```
function toArray(o) {
  return Array.isArray(o) ? o.slice() : [o];
};
```

Comment: Yeah it would work but it's actually exactly the same code, just written as a ternary. I'm looking for something else, like a single method. But I actually doubt it exists :)

Comment: You're not really converting an object to an array, it looks like you're just returning a new array both if it's already an array and if it's a string, so I don't think there is a built in function that does both without some type checking and two different methods, like above.

Comment: Yep you're right, I'm not really converting it. I edited the question to make it more clear. Thanks :)

Comment: From some of the answers it seems you can just join it with an existing array using concat(), and create an array, regardless of wether or not it's a string or array, so that's neat, even if it does pretty much the same thing.

Comment: Yeah I accepted the `concat()` way. No need for a new function with it

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can slice it:

```
var fooObj = {0: 123, 1: 'bar', length: 2};
var fooArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(fooObj);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sh5R9/

Comment: you cannot. in chrome at least not.

Comment: For numeric keys, sure -- `{ 0: 123, 1: 'bar', length: 2 }`. But, I think the OP is after `Array`-wrapping more than direct conversion.

Comment: It's not really what I'm looking for. I want to put the object as the first entry of an array (if it's not already one). So the expected result with your object would be: `[{0: 123, 1: 'bar', length: 2}]`. But it's nice to know that you can call slice on an object!